# Get an error when retrieving files from a mapped network drive

Tags: powershell, network-drive

I am creating a mapped network drive in PowerShell, but have some weird behavior when retrieving files from the drive. When I create the drive (without `-Persist -Scope Global`):

```
$somePath = "\\testtest.lan\Res\Application\TestApp\SomeFiles"

$PsDrive = New-PSDrive -Name "M" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root $somePath

Get-ChildItem "M:\" -Recurse | Select-Object -Property *, @{n='Path';e={$_.FullName -replace [regex]::Escape("M:\")}}
```

On my first attempt to do `Get-Child` as mentioned above I get an error saying:

> "Get-ChildItem: Length cannot be less than zero"

Immediately on my second attempt it works just fine and I can see all the files listed. Next time I try it is stops working(in the same session) with a different error:

> Get-ChildItem : An unexpected network error occurred.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Get-ChildItem "M:\" -Recurse
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (\testtest.l..er\Res\Application\TestApp\SomeFiles:String) [Get-ChildItem], IOException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

When I try to create the mapped network drive like this:

```
New-PSDrive -Name "M" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root $somePath -Persist -Scope Global
```

It works immediately couple of times, but it just stops working after some time with the same error as above:

> Get-ChildItem : An unexpected network error occurred.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Get-ChildItem "M:\" -Recurse
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (\testtest.l..er\Res\Application\TestApp\SomeFiles:String) [Get-ChildItem], IOException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

When I do `Get-PsDrive` I can see the mapped drive there.

Am I doing something wrong in the code or some problem with the network location I am trying to access. It shouldn't be related to permissions since there are times when it's working correctly or maybe it could be. I am able to access the network location when I try from File Explorer.

Let me know your thinking about this.

Thanks,

Andrej

Comment: Does `$somePath` begin with an IP address or a DNS name? May your network contain any methods for redundancy? Do you observe any network problems? May there be a user who plugged both ends of a network cable into a switch ("just to keep it clean from dust while not in use")? Is there a user that may have configured the same IP address as you?

Comment: Are you sure that the fully qualified of the files names are less than 260 characters, and the directories names less than 248 characters ?

Comment: Does the problem persist if you replace `testtest.lan` by the corresponding IP address? If yes, then we can exclude DNS problems.

Comment: I'm sure that file names and directories names are less than 100 characters. I can't believe that after I shared my post here, every time I run it, works perfectly fine. Haven't seen any error for hours. I'll continue to monitor the situation and let you know what will happen.